# How to load Bitmap and setbitmap on an ImageView that is on the main screen from recyclerview inside framelayout?

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview, imageview

I am making an application to change the image after applying some effects on it.  The image is at the main screen, and on the same screen,there is a framelayout containing several recyclerviews. I want to click an item in recyclerview so imageview changes.

Before using navigationview (framelayout) I only had recyclerview, from which I could manage the ImageView perfectly (from onBind.... function). However, since I wanted it to be in a frame to be able to change to other buttons, I moved the code to other Class, so when I do findviewbyid, i get null so I cannot do any work.
I have been searching a lot and trying many things but still I dont have any clue.
Someone has got any idea?

Comment: Please add relevant code in question to support this long story. That would be easy to understand.

Comment: Add the code that you have tried.